# Directing all mobile traffic to AMP pages on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, amp-html

I'm building a WooCommerce website and I'd like to know if I can force a redirect of all mobile traffic to the AMP pages of the shop. This is kind of a test as I have about 11 client websites running on regular responsive templates.

Would it be possible to force a redirect to AMP on mobile? And how can I exclude the checkout pages while doing this because I understand they're not converted at the moment

Answer (score 1):

This bit of htaccess code should do the trick for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot\-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|\#opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ https://example.com/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/amp-woocommerce/ - that should do the job

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with this. The only problem being that the AMP pages only show up when the user clicks through from a supported platform like Google search.

I'd like the AMP pages to show up by default for all mobile users